# Build a single table from one column of each of 240 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can get a list of all columns in all tables, on SQL Server 2019 (v15.04):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%(xx)%' -- new tables under development
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%archive%'
```

But how can I concatenate the data from all those tables into 1 table? There are 240 tables listed above.

So let's assume that all tables have a column called `objectID` (they do). How do I get the column `objectID` from 240 tables, into one table?

I can't find the solution. The main issue being that the "select from" is a list of tables.

Comment: You build a union all that selects from each of those tables by using dynamic sql

Comment: If you don't need to run it programmatically you could also just script out the `selects` and `unions` then paste the results to be run

Comment: Something like `select concat('select myfield from dbo.', quotename(name), ' union all') from sys.tables` then copy paste the results to query window and lop off the final `union all`

Comment: Thanks... I've been doing a form of that... just thought there was a secret magic bullet that would work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to script out the `union all` (or `union`, if you want distinct values) and then execute it somehow. If you just need to run it ad-hoc, you can do something like:

```
select concat
    (
        'select OBJECT_ID from ', 
        quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA), 
        '.', 
        quotename(TABLE_NAME),
        ' union all'
    )
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME  not like '%(xx)%' -- new tables under development
    and TABLE_NAME  not like '%archive%'
    and COLUMN_NAME = 'OBJECT_ID' -- make sure the column _actually_ exists
```

Then copy/paste those into a query window, lop off the final `union all` and execute them. I do this all the time when I need to run commands across a bunch of tables.

If you want to be able to run it programmatically, it's better to concatenate all the union statements altogether. Here's how you could do it with dynamic sql:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
select @SQL = string_agg
    (
        concat
        (
            'select OBJECT_ID from ', 
            quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA), 
            '.', 
            quotename(TABLE_NAME)
        ), 
        ' union all '
    )
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME  not like '%(xx)%' -- new tables under development
    and TABLE_NAME  not like '%archive%'
    and COLUMN_NAME = 'OBJECT_ID' -- make sure the column _actually_ exists

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Note that I put in an extra criterion to check that the column `OBJECT_ID` actually exists which means I'll only be getting a single row for each table. If you plan to execute this programmatically without inspecting the results first, I'd recommend you ensure this.

If you have multiple columns, or don't want to do that check, you can just `DISTINCT` the results to collapse all the columns you don't care about.

Comment: Thanks ... never used dynamic sql before... something new to learn.

Comment: It's a powerful tool which should be used sparingly. If you _really_ want to go deep down the rabbit hole of understanding the ins and outs of dynamic sql, you can't do much better than this group of articles on [The Curses and Blessing of Dynamic Sql](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog.